# I want to change a wav file with 44100 sr to 22050 sr with out change in pitch and speed in python

Tags: python, audio, librosa, soundfile

This is my code:

```
list_ = os.listdir("All_wavs")
for i,val in enumerate(list_):
  
    y, sr = librosa.load(f"All_wavs/{val}")
    data = librosa.resample(y, orig_sr =44100,target_sr= 22050)
    sf.write(f"wavs/{val}",data, samplerate =22050)
```

it works but the wav files sound different

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[librosa.load](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.load.html#librosa.load) automatically resamples the input signal to 22050 unless specified otherwise, you could modify that using `sr` if you want and just save it, you don't need to do a second downsampling.

```py
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

list_ = os.listdir("All_wavs")
for i,val in enumerate(list_):
    y, sr = librosa.load(f"All_wavs/{val}", sr=22050)
    sf.write(f"wavs/{val}",y, samplerate =22050)
```

Comment: I know it is 44100

Comment: will the new files have the same audio sound as with 44100 sr?

Comment: @MaxMelichov there is some lost high frequency data, the audio might not be "as crisp", but it will sound like it's the same person talking.